# Find the expected value and the variance of the time at which the plumber completes the project

Tags: probability, proof-verification

This is a problem 8 from Chapter 8 "Introduction to probability" by Anderson:

> Our faucet is broken, and a plumber has been called. The arrival time
>   of the plumber is uniformly distributed between 1pm and 7pm. The time
>   required to fix the broken faucet is then exponentially distributed
>   with mean 30 minutes. Supposing that the two times are independent,
>   find the expected value and the variance of the time at which the
>   plumber completes the project.

I've solved it, but I am not sure if I interpreted the statement of the problem (translated into the language of probability distribution) correctly. So let X be the arrival time of the plumber, then $X\sim Unif[1,7]$. Let Y be the time it takes to fix the broken faucet, then $Y\sim Exp(2)$. Let Z be the time at which the plumber completes the project, then $Z=X+Y$. Now $E[Z]=E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=\frac{1+7}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=4.5$
$Var(Z) = \text{(since X and Y are independent)} \ Var(X)+Var(Y) = \frac{{(7-1)}^2}{12}+\frac{1}{2^2}=3.25$

Are there any mistakes in my solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. You have identified the distributions -and their mean and variance- correctly, and used the right equations -including the effect of independance-. If the calculations are okay, then you have it.